# Суммировать значения диапазона ячеек в столбцах, выбираемых по условию

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Не могу найти решение по следующим проблемам:

1) как осуществить суммирование всех значений массива, которые расположены на пересечении строк и столбца, соответствующих условий. **Пример ниже подсвечены — я хочу в ячейки верхней(рабочей) таблицы добавить суммы значений из нижней(исходник)**:

использую формулы

атомарно для E7

```
=ИНДЕКС($B$10:$S$37;

ПОИСКПОЗ($B7&"*";
$B$10:$B$36;
0);

ПОИСКПОЗ(E$2;
$B$10:$S$10;
0))
```

строчно для F6

```
=ИНДЕКС($B$10:$S$37;ПОИСКПОЗ($B6&"*";$B$10:$B$36;0);ПОИСКПОЗ(F$2;$B$10:$S$10;0))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно использую конструкцию `ПОИСКПОЗ($B6&"*";`

**но на выходе получаю только первое вхождение из массива. Не пойму как суммировать(**

2) вторая задача вытекает из первой:

в столбцы H and I рабочей таблицы мне необходимо поместить значения заголовков исходника, по следующей логике:

для H:

тот заголовок, в столбце которого содержаться значения(числа) только от непрямого вхождения названия строки (с "* ф").

**те если есть значения в "Названия строк" исходника содержится "ф_"**

для I:
заголовок, который содержит прямое и непрямое/расширенное вхождение.

**те если есть значения в "Названия строк" исходника "ф_" и без.**

К сожалению не смог самостоятельно разобраться в сложной конструкции.

**Ссылка на сам файл:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B42T65A5ALWQyq3K-V7sKzWRfPU4Vt0S

Comment: Надо пример оказывать в файле. На картинках формулы можно написать фломастером, но проверить работоспособность не получится )

Comment: @vikttur согласен с вами, поправил пост. Попробую решить с помощью вашего комментария, спасибо!

Comment: @vikttur
up: оба решения по суммированию числовых значений отработали отлично. 

Относительно пункта 2: 
UDF-VBA — пока непосильное для меня знание. Но попробую изучить вопрос со временем.
Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Это функция, которая пишется на *VBA*. На листе вводится как  формула.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наброски (проверять не на чем). Возможно, даже работают :)

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ((ЛЕВБ($B$11:$B$36;5)=$B3)*($C$10:$S$10=C$2)*$C$11:$S$36)
```

`СУММЕСЛИ` лучше, работает быстрее:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ($B$11:$B$36;$B3&"*";ИНДЕКС($C$11:$S$36;;ПОИСКПОЗ(C$2;$C$10:$S$10;)))
```

Для столбцов *H:I* лучше всего подойдет функция пользователя (*UDF-VBA*). Это совсем другой вопрос и задавать его нужно отдельно. Или комплексно - на фриланс-площадке.